# nginx enable http2 for ssl by default

Tags: nginx

У меня есть много сайтов на nginx. И для каждого из них мне надо поправить:

```
listen 443 ssl;
```

на

```
listen 443 ssl http2;
```

Есть более простой метод включения http2 по умолчанию?

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык. заодно и приведите вопрос [в порядок: чтобы было понятно, с чем именно у вас трудности, что вы пробовали сделать, какие ошибки получили и т.д. и т.п.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что у Вас много конфигов nginx, и не хочется в каждом руками дописывать 'http2' ?

Comment: Ну это уже вопрос организации конфига, надо было раньше все одинаковые куски выносить в отдельный файл (или файлы) и инклудить :)

Comment: Если да, то способов есть более, чем достаточно, к примеру, так:
find ./ -iname "*.conf" -type f -exec sed -i 's/listen 443 ssl;/listen 443 ssl http2;/gi' {} \;
Хотя я не уверен, что сработает. Но суть. я думаю, вы поняли, при помощи bash скрипта это делает в одну строку.

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik проверил у себя, работает)

Comment: Я думал возможно есть ручка чтоб включить везде. 
Спасибо, действительно достаточно просто обновить все bash скриптом.